# Рекурсивный поиск буднего дня

Tags: php, дата, рекурсия

Мне нужно получить количество дней до первого буднего дня через 4 дня после текущей даты, но функция daysBeforeTask() мне возвращает 4(значение по умолчанию), хотя если сделать dd($days) перед return, то он отобразит 6 (то что мне нужно). В чем может быть проблема?

```php
function isWeekend($date)
{
    $isWeekend = false;
    $numberOfTheWeek = date('N', $date);
    if (($numberOfTheWeek >= 6) && ($numberOfTheWeek <= 7)) {
        $isWeekend = true;
    }
    return $isWeekend;
}

function daysBeforeTask($days = 4)
{
    $date = strtotime("+$days day");
    if (isWeekend($date)) {
        daysBeforeTask($days + 1);
    }
    // dd($days);
    return $days;
}
```

Comment: А что за функция `dd()`?

Comment: @LaukhinAndrey примерно тоже самое что и var_dump

Comment: Тогда ясно. Вы забыли про возвращаемое значение: `$days = daysBeforeTask($days + 1)`. Должно заработать. Ниже я предлагаю более простой вариант без рекурсии.

Comment: @LaukhinAndrey Спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Предлагаю упростить само решение:

```
$num = 4;

$targetwday = date('N', strtotime("+{$num} days"));
$extradays = $targetwday > 5 ? 8 - $targetwday : 0;
$days = $num + $extradays;

$targetdate = strtotime("+{$days} days");
```

Или еще короче без strtotime():

```
$now = time();
$days = ($twd = date('N', $now + 86400 * $num)) > 5 ? 8 - $twd + $num : $num;
$targetdate = $now + 86400 * $days;
```